# Who exactly is the target of Super User?

Tags: discussion

My understanding of the primary trifecta of Stack Exchange websites was challenged by [my question](https://superuser.com/q/618111/225086) on Super User. I used to think that between Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault you could get any computer related question answered. Stack Overflow containing answers for developers, Server Fault for server administrators, and Super User for end users.

Then I discovered that website based applications, despite being targeted at end-users does not qualify for Super User. If Super User is not meant to target End-Users then what exactly is the target for Super User?

Comment: I'm not an expert on set theory, but I think your logic is flawed.

Comment: I think he meant web applications such as Gmail, YouTube, Facebook and all that is related in terms of their usability and problems that could arise from using those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then I discovered that website based applications, despite being targeted at end-users does not qualify for Super User. If Super User is not meant to target End-Users then what exactly is the target for Super User?

First off, you can ask questions about web applications on [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Our target is computer software or hardware that you own and control. Anything that belongs to you, runs on your machine, etc. Websites or web services are *not* computer software in that sense.

You can check our scope by visiting our [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), which also specifically mentions that questions about web services are off topic.

That being said, we do of course focus on end users (or power users) of computers, and your classification in general is not that off—except that there are more subtleties in how each of the sites defines their scope. For example, not every developer question is suitable for Stack Overflow, but might be more on topic for [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh, I did not know of the webapps site. I guess the discussions I read here on such apps predate it's existence.